# Wi-fi connection iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to find, and list name of an available wifi connections in tableview...Reachability  code can determine whether the wifi connection is available or not... I want to find names also

Can any one help me?

thanks in advance.......

Comment: To accept answers, you click the green check mark (its an outline until you select one) right under the vote count on each answer. http://img.skitch.com/20091128-86ph7yhfbps8yeduc4eisxetem.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is not available using public APIs. You can only determine whether or not the device is currently connected to a Wifi network using the techniques in the Reachability example. You cannot access a list of available access points nor manipulate the wireless connection.

If you would like to file an enhancement request for to make such APIs public, I suggest your file a bug report on http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Any attempts to access such information through private APIs or other means is likely to be grounds for a quick (or rather, not so quick) rejection of your application during the App Store review process.